# python program running functions simultaneously instead of running sequentially

Tags: python, websocket, algorithmic-trading, binance

With the below program I am trying to

- Create an order using binance-connector lib then
- Check status of the created order using user data socket streaming(unicorn-binance-websocket-api),
- Once I get an update from the socket stream that the status of the order is filled, I want to close the stream and move on to create the next order.

The issue I am facing is that, while the websocket stream is running, the program is moving on to create the 2nd order without waiting for the websocket connection to stop. It is basically running stream() and main_algo() simultaneously. Whereas, I want the stream() to finish before proceeding with next line under main_algo(). Where am I going wrong?

```
from binance.futures import Futures
from unicorn_binance_websocket_api.manager import BinanceWebSocketApiManager
import threading

binance_websocket_api_manager = BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange="binance.com-futures-testnet", throw_exception_if_unrepairable=True)
stream_id = binance_websocket_api_manager.create_stream('arr', '!userData', api_key=api_key, api_secret=secret_key)

client = Futures(api_key, secret_key, base_url="https://testnet.binancefuture.com")


def stream(binance_websocket_api_manager):
    global order_id 

    while True:
        if binance_websocket_api_manager.is_manager_stopping():
            exit(0)
        oldest_stream_data_from_stream_buffer = binance_websocket_api_manager.pop_stream_data_from_stream_buffer()
        if oldest_stream_data_from_stream_buffer is False:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        else:
            print(oldest_stream_data_from_stream_buffer)
            # if status of created order is filled:
                binance_websocket_api_manager.stop_manager_with_all_streams() # stop connection

def order_status():
    worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(binance_websocket_api_manager,))
    worker_thread.start()

def main_algo():
    client.new_order(symbol, price, quantity, 'BUY') #(1st Order)
    order_status() #start websocket to check for order status
    print('first order filled')
    #create next order
    print('creating second order')
    client.new_order(symbol, price, quantity, 'BUY') #(2nd Order)

main_algo()
```

Comment: Looks like `binance.futures.Futures()` returns promises, which are needed to be awaited. Try to await them `await client.new_order(symbol, price, quantity, 'BUY')`

Comment: You need to use `asyncio` event loops. A good place to start learning about `asyncio` is in this [tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/asyncio-event-loops-tutorial/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264001/9170226) is an implementation with deribit exchange but you can use it for binance as well.

Comment: Also i'm confused as to why you are using two different libraries. `binance.futures` uses RestAPI while `unicorn_binance_websocket_api` uses `websockets`. Websockets works much better than RestAPI so why not just use that?

Comment: @AlexB thanks for links, I was planning to get up to speed with asyncio so this will be helpful. As to why I am using both libraries - I previously built with binance.futures and was planning to use the same for this one but binance-connector websocket currently has some issues, hence this mixture. Eventually, I want it to be all on websockets.

Comment: I understand. Also (maybe you don't know the answer) why use `unicorn_binance_websocket_api` for websockets? Why not use `websockets` or `websocket-client`? I'm curious because I use `websockets` to connect to other exchanges that I use and I was wondering what the benefit was of using `unicorn_binance_websocket_api` instead of the generic websocket libraries.